# Getting NullPointerException with multiple classes applet

Tags: java, html, applet, nullpointerexception

I have been developing a Java Applet game during the last month and now I'm trying to embed it in an HTML page. I'm getting **NullPointerException** everytime, despite of having signed my .jar already following the next code:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore myKeyStore -alias me
keytool -selfcert -keystore myKeyStore -alias me
jarsigner -keystore myKeyStore Franky.jar me
```

Once I try to run it on this page where I'm currently working: http://zeytpruebas.prosopin.com/index.html it seems my .jar still being unsigned/author unknown. My game runs error-free via Eclipse IDE and my embedding code is error-free too because I tested it with a simple HelloWorld applet.

Otherwise, there is my embed code:

`<applet code="franky_BF38/Principal.class" archive="Franky.jar" width="800"  height="480"></applet>`

On the other hand, my .jar looks like this:

> audio (folder)
>
> > · franky_theme.au
>
> images (folder)
>
> > · 1.jpg
> >
> > · 2.jpg
>
> levels (folder)
>
> > · map1.txt
> >
> > · map2.txt
>
> franky_BF38 (folder of classes)
>
> > · Principal.class (which is the main class)
> >
> > · Enemy.class
> >
> > · Player.class (...)
>
> META-INF (folder)
>
> > · MANIFEST.MF
> >
> > · ME.DSA
> >
> > · ME.SF

I have looked at all the applet threads, and no response is working for me. If you need any piece of code or archives feel free to ask. Any help would be appreciated so much.

**EDIT**: Added thread dump by Java Console on my page (due to a long extension): [dump](http://zeytpruebas.prosopin.com/stacktrace.txt)

**EDIT 02/05/2013**: In reference to the warning of _constructor does not initialize fields [imagen_actual, fondo, franky_salto...]_ I have the following code below the class Principal:

```
private Image imagen, franky, franky_agachado, franky_salto, fondo,
        imagen_actual, pacifista;
public static Image tilegrassTop, tilegrassBot, tilegrassLeft,
        tilegrassRight, tiledirt, tileocean;
private Graphics graficos;
private URL direccion;
AudioClip disparo, tema;
```

Then I assign valors directly to those variables in init() method, like this (no initializing):

```
try {
        direccion = getDocumentBase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    franky = getImage(direccion, "imagenes/franky_estatico.png");
    franky_agachado = getImage(direccion, "imagenes/franky_sentado.png");
    franky_salto = getImage(direccion, "imagenes/franky_salto.png");
    imagen_actual = franky;
    pacifista = getImage(direccion, "imagenes/pacifista1.png");
    fondo = getImage(direccion, "imagenes/background.png");

    tiledirt = getImage(direccion, "imagenes/tiledirt.png");
    tilegrassTop = getImage(direccion, "imagenes/tilegrasstop.png");
    tilegrassBot = getImage(direccion, "imagenes/tilegrassbot.png");
    tilegrassLeft = getImage(direccion, "imagenes/tilegrassleft.png");
    tilegrassRight = getImage(direccion, "imagenes/tilegrassright.png");

    disparo = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "audio/miss.au");
    tema = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "audio/franky_theme.au");
```

As said previously, code runs error-free in Eclipse but Checker Framework is advicing about this.

Comment: Did you copy all locally to an empty directory, and test the applet stand-alone, outside eclipse? You might add a try-catch and dump the stacktrace too.

Comment: @JoopEggen As this is my first time with Applet let me ask you a very stupid question: how can I test it stand-alone outside Eclipse? I'm working on Windows by the way.

Comment: Simply an HTML file with the jar in one directory. BTW everyone begins somewhere.

Comment: @JoopEggen Well, actually I'm already doing this. I have a FTP with my jar and the HTML file on the same directory. If I'm not understanding you wrong...

Comment: Simply copy the HTML and jar to some directory on your own PC (so outside eclipse), Then drag the HTML onto browser (a URL "file://,,, ,html").

Comment: @JoopEggen Getting the same exception everytime. I'm actually desperate.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the NPE?  *"I'm getting NullPointerException everytime, despite of having signed my .jar already following the next code:"*  The NPE is not related to security.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Should I add a StackTrace in each try/catch block? Apparently the "Details" of the Java Console aren't showing any interesting.

Comment: Try turning the output of the console to 5.  But yes, definitely dump the stack trace.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I must apologize, didn't even know the functionality of Java Console. I uploaded the dump on my page: [link](http://zeytpruebas.prosopin.com/stacktrace.txt)

Comment: [Edit it into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16302981/edit) (& use code formatting on that as well)!  ..and there is probably no need for a level 5 trace, just make sure the code calls `Throwable.printStackTrace()`..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29234/discussion-between-zeyt-and-andrew-thompson)

Comment: No thanks.  Not up for chat.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I added a exception.printStackTrace in every try/catch block in my whole code. It still happens the same and not showing any information. I can upload my project if you want; I can be doing something wrong as I'm pretty new with Java and Applet's world.

Comment: *"I can upload my project if you want"*  No I don't.  These types of problems should be sorted in a short code.  If the code is short, post it as an edit.

Comment: @AndrewThompson My code isn't short. Have multiple classes as well, that's why I guess would be better to upload it somewhere. Furthermore, as I'm not getting any error via Eclipse I have no clues about where the problem could be.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Check for **case-sensitive** paths; Windows would accept both Map1.txt and map1.txt; but java not in a jar.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Of course I can do that, but how am I supposed to short my code If I got 0 clues about where's my problem exactly?

Apparently all paths are fine.

Comment: *"how am I supposed to short my code"*  There is more to SSCCE than 'short'.  If you had read the article, you would know that.  It gives many tips.

Comment: I have found a **Checker Framework** for nullables, there is what he says: _constructor does not initialize fields [imagen_actual, fondo..._ and _incompatible types in argument_ for the following code:
`private Font font = new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 30);`
I'll edit question with more info in a minute.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Main question edited with Checker Framework information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours debugging finally Java Console decided to provide some good info about the exception. Apparently Java does not like so much those lines of code inside the browser:

```
Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent(); 
frame.setTitle("Franky BF38, the Iron Pirate");
```

I removed it and now works fine despite of having some bugs that I'll fix soon. Hope this'll help other users in a future. Thanks to all for contribute.